# Convert output of script(1) to pdf

Tags: terminal, pdf, printing

You supposedly can make some sort of low-tech replacement to screencasts of your terminal sessions with script(1):

```
DESCRIPTION

script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal.  It
is useful for students who need a hardcopy  record  of  an  interactive
session  as  proof  of  an  assignment,  as  the typescript file can be
printed out later with lpr(1).
```

I now created a typescript file. But how do I make a readable pdf from it?

I used lp with the printer PDF from cups-pdf but the output is garbled. There are lots of `m`, `0;` and `34;42` where should be blanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A utility that seems to work quite well with handling ansi escapes and input line editing from a typescript is [ansi2html.sh](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh) which obviously generates html. You can either view this output in your browser and use its printing features, or, if you dont mind losing the colours, convert the html back to simple text with no escapes, eg with

```
ansi2html.sh <mytypescript | w3m -dump -T text/html >out.txt
```

You can then use `enscript` to print simple text files.

Comment: I think https://github.com/theZiz/aha works better

Comment: I found `aha` didnt handle backspaces in the commands typed in to bash, for example, whereas `ansi2html.sh` did. So typing `abc\b\b\bdef` (where `\b` represents a backspace) showed as `abcdef` in the former, but `def` in the latter.

Answer (score 3):

There's two choices:

- replay the script (with pauses, even via [XOFF/XON](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator/72092#72092)), and make screenshots which some tool may convert into PDF
- strip the control sequences from the file, leaving a plain-text file that can be converted into PDF.

Generally I've done the latter; both have their pitfalls.  When making screenshots, you may not get exactly the picture you wanted (though using [`scriptreplay`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scriptreplay.1.html), it's possible to slow things down to make it simpler to pause the screen).  Filtering escape sequences works well enough for command-line applications such as "colorized ls", but poorly for screenshots of a text editor.

Further reading:

- [How to clean stdout/stderr color output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183733/how-to-clean-stdout-stderr-color-output)
- [Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils/28334291#28334291)

Answer (score 0):

The counterpart of `script(1)` is `scriptreplay(1)`:

```
DESCRIPTION
    This  program  replays  a typescript, using timing 
    information to ensure that output happens at the same 
    speed as it originally appeared when the script was recorded.
```

Also, `scriptreplay` provides option to speed up/slow down the replay.

Thus, you can't just print it. You could replay it and capture screenshots or make a movie.

Comment: How do you know for sure, that one just **can't** print it? It even says it can be printed in the manpage.

Comment: Of course it can be printed as any text document with one exception: 
"Certain  interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the typescript file.  Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal." (from the same man page). Did you use `vi` or alike? I meant exactly your case: you have such garbage in the script

Comment: Another thing that may produce 'garbage' is colored text output.